# Sum 2 columns in inner joined table with SQL

Tags: sql

I imagine this should be relatively easy for anyone who knows a little SQL.

Here is my current script:

```
SELECT t1.Invoice_Number
      ,t1.Override_Cashier_ID
      ,t1.Exception_Type
      ,t1.ItemNum
      ,t1.Amount
      ,t1.Quantity
      ,t1.Amount*t1.Quantity AS Total
      ,t1.Reason_Code
      ,t2.DateTime
  FROM [esql].[dbo].[Invoice_Exceptions] AS t1
  INNER JOIN [esql].[dbo].[Invoice_Totals] AS t2
  ON  t1.Invoice_Number = t2.Invoice_Number
  WHERE t1.Exception_Type = 2
  AND CAST(t2.DateTime as date) > '20160127'
  AND CAST(t2.DateTime as date) < '20170101'
```

I want to accomplish 2 things:

1. Sum the 'Total' column, something like:  sum(t1.Amount*t1.Quantity) AS Total
2. Group those by 'Reason_Code' which is a string.  Let's say Reason code contains 2 different value possibilities, "me" and "you".  I would want to only display 2 rows after the query runs, 1 for each reason code that contains the summed value.

Some Sample Data would be:

The Quantity and Amount columns are both decimals.  I would expect the final data to look something like:

```
Reason_Code  -  Total  -  Date_Range
Me              4000      2016-01-27 - 2017-01-01
You             3500      2016-01-27 - 2017-01-01


Where some sample data may be:

Invoice_Number  -  Reason_Code  -  Amount  -  Quantity  -  Total  -  DateTime
12345              Me              500        2            1000      2016-01-29 21:24:07.000
12346              Me              1000       3            3000      2016-01-29 23:15:19.000
12347              You             500        1            500       2016-01-29 19:00:17.000
12348              You             1000       3            3000      2016-01-29 21:46:29.000
```

I hope this is concise enough!  Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

So using suggestions so far, I realized I had way too much data brought in that SQL didnt know what to do with.  I now have this and am 95% there:

```
SELECT
    sum(t1.Amount*t1.Quantity) AS Total
    ,t1.Reason_Code

    FROM [esql].[dbo].[Invoice_Exceptions] AS t1
    INNER JOIN [esql].[dbo].[Invoice_Totals] AS t2

    ON  t1.Invoice_Number = t2.Invoice_Number

    WHERE t1.Exception_Type = 2
    AND CAST(t2.DateTime as date) > '20160127'
    AND CAST(t2.DateTime as date) < '20170101'

    GROUP BY t1.Reason_Code
```

Any way to display the Date Range now?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Or at least your tables schema? Ideally, you should provide a setup script that creates the tables and populates them with some dummy data. This would be very helpful for those who want to provide a tested answer.

Comment: I made an edit to my original post.  I have it mostly working but just need to display the Date Range, if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you could do just what you are suggesting:
add a `GROUP BY Reason_Code` clause and use `sum(t1.Amount*t1.Quantity) AS Total` in your `SELECT` statement. But you would *also* need to define how to deal with the other columns you'd like to include in your two rows. Either you have to add them to the `GROUP BY` or you have to find an appropriate aggregate function to determine which value to include.